Error observed while setting up AVD as "An error occurred while creating AVD. See idea.log for details" in Android Studio
Error observed while setting up AVD as "An error occurred while creating AVD. See idea.log for details".
Tried reinstalling Android studio, emulators, platform-tools.. none worked
Creating virtual device in Android studio

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you are on windows, you can try deleting all files from your Users/{username}/.android/avd folder
Then restart Studio and try installing a virtual device.
Also, you might encounter problems in case you have blank spaces in your windows user folder or your project file name.
If you can share the log mentioned it might help.

Glad it helped! Could you please accept the answer and also mention if the problem went away by deleting the files or removing the white spaces
